# Call certain function from a list of similar functions

Tags: javascript, function

Imagine an array 100k rows long (no matter how many columns).

I have a 100 javascript functions which are almost identical but every one should work with it's own 1000 of rows.

I want to call necessary function or few of them at any time based on some conditions.

For example, if based on condition I need to work with 5th thousand of rows of the array, I should call 5th function.

One more condition: function should be called at certain time. This means that few functions can be called at the same time, that's why I can't use just one function with different arguments.

I thought I can name functions as 'function1', 'function2', .., 'functionN'. But I don't know how to call them with condition.

I think maybe there is a way like:

```
if (someVar == 5) {
   function5();
}
```

If there such way to call a function in javascript?
I appreciate any help.

Comment: I don't understand your question, but whenever you have numbered variable names, you should probably use an array instead: `functions[someVar]()`.

Comment: `function` is a keyword. You can't use that as a name for an array

Comment: but I can't get why `functions[5]()` will call my `function5()`..

Comment: It won't. It will call `functions[5]`. My point is that you shouldn't have a `function5`.

Comment: @melpomene please explain or tell if I've got it right. If I'll have an array like `var functions = ["one", "two", "three"];` I'll be able to call `function two()` like `functions[1]();`?

Comment: Let me see if I understand, you have an array with 100 functions and another one with 100 000 rows of different data, each function must operate with a portion of that array of data based in a certain condition? what is that condition?

Comment: No, that's an array of strings, not an array of functions. You'd have `var functions = [one, two, three];` or simply `var functions = [ function () { ... }, function () { ... }, ... ]`; then you don't even need a `function one()`, `function two()`, etc.

Comment: The condition result is the number (like 5 in example) which means the number of function that should be called. Like if we caught 5 => we'll call `function5`.

Comment: @melpomene thank you very much, I'll try it. Will you write an answer for I be able to accept it? Or there is no need for that? (I'm a newbie, that's why I'm asking)

Comment: Just my two cents-- if you have 100 functions that are "almost identical", [you are probably doing something wrong in your overall design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself).  See if you can turn it into a single function that takes an argument to account for the small amount of variance between the functions, or perhaps pull out the identical portion from the 100 functions and encapsulate it into its own function.

Comment: @anied I've mentioned that, functions sometimes run at once, that's why I can't use one with arguments.

Comment: @АндрійБойко -- perhaps I am misunderstanding something, but I see no reason this precludes you from using the same function with several different arguments.  I'm not trying to be difficult, but I'm using comments instead of answering your question because I think the question itself may be based on some flawed design-- I'd like to challenge you to review that design and see if perhaps there is a better way to solve your problem. Again, just my opinion-- I don't know enough about your specific scenario, but my hunch is that you've got some anti-patterns.

Comment: @АндрійБойко This sounds like an XY problem. You should give a clear explanation of what these functions actually do and why you need so many. As anied points out, there is probably a better way, but you have asked us to fix the approach you've already picked rather than asking for help with the actual problem. _"functions sometimes run at once"_ makes zero sense in terms of explaining why you can't parameterize them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can assign functions to an array. ie:

```
var funct = [];
funct[5] = function (...) { ... }
```

and then you can call them like this:

```
if (someVar == 5) {
    funct[5]();
}
```

it's also good idea to use more descriptive keys for functions, you can think of it as of function names. but in this case you should use object instead of an array. ie:

```
var funct = {};
funct['send-data'] = function (...) { ... }

if (someVar == 5) {
    funct['send-data']();
}
```

Comment: If you're going to use non-numeric keys, you shouldn't use an array. That's what objects are for.

Comment: @rsm thank you for help. That's exactly what I've asked for.